# PHP generate and send emails with broken link

Tags: php, email, hyperlink

and sorry for my english.

I build a link with php.
I send it by email.
Some times the link (in the email) is broken.

When I do click (or copy to the browser) has been inserted in a random position a blank space.

any idea?

generate mail, code like this:

```
$url="www.example.com/dir/subdir/page.php?param1=$p1&param2=$p2&param3=$p3[...]&param20=$p20";
    [...]
    $body .= "<td><a href=\"$url\">";
    $body .= htmlentities($url,ENT_NOQUOTES,'ISO-8859-1');
    $body .= "</a></td>";
    [...]

$headers  = "From: $companyName < $companyMail > \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $companyMail \r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1 ";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0 ";

mail($client, "Confirmaton", $body, $headers);
```

Example recived params on page.php

code:

```
echo "<pre>Request:<br>";
print_r($_REQUEST);
echo "</pre><br>";
exit;


case OK:
Request:
Array
(
    [p1] => value1
    [p2] => value2
    [p3] => value3
    [p3] => value5
    [p4] => value6
    [p5] => value7
    (...)
    [p20] => value20

)

Error1 (link with space in value)
Request:
Array
(
    [p1] => value1
    [p2] => val ue2
    [p3] => value3
    [p3] => value5
    [p4] => value6
    [p5] => value7
    (...)
    [p20] => value20

)

Error2 (link with space in variable)
Request:
Array
(
    [p1] => value1
    [p2] => value2
    [p_3] => value3
    [p3] => value5
    [p4] => value6
    [p5] => value7
    (...)
    [p20] => value20

)
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of an url giving you links with space ?

Comment: I suspect you need [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) rather than `htmlentities()`.

Comment: Might not fix it, but you need to add `http://` try `$url="http://www.example.com...` because the link won't be clickable in most email clients.

Comment: Most mail clients insert a line break after a certain number of characters (e.g. 80 characters). If you copy & paste a line break into your browser bar, it becomes as space.

Comment: I add: http:// at beginning of url, urlencode like this ?param1=".urlencode($p1)."&param2=".urlencode($p2).", and style=\"white-space:nowrap;\" at the <td> that contain the link. Seems to have worked in a few tests

Comment: I get sometimes the same problem and can't find where it's coming from :/

Answer (score 0):

Try to force php to avoid wrapping the link:

```
$link = wordwrap($url, 255, "\r\n");
```

That may be caused by the line breaks that every mail client put into email bodies.

Answer (score 0):

The space und the line break wich will break your url. It is not a bug. It is the Limit of a line by your smtp server.
So the RFC 2821 and 5321 define a maximum line length :
The maximum total length of a text line including the  is 1000 (sometimes it is 990)
octets (not counting the leading dot duplicated for transparency).
This number may be increased by the use of SMTP Service Extensions.

The solution my be a line feed after each `<td>` or `<tr>`.

```
$body .= "<td><a href=\"$url\">";
$body .= htmlentities($url,ENT_NOQUOTES,'ISO-8859-1');
$body .= "</a></td>\n";
```